# How do I exclude a specific row in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to return information from my database but I would like to output last news a litlle differend than other.

I managed to get last news with the following code

```
$finalNews = News::find(DB::table('news')->max('id'));
```

But than I have another variable which return all the rows from `News` table with the following code

```
$news = News::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

I want to exclude the news row which is equal to `$finalNews`
at the end of controller I return view with following data

```
return view('news', ['news' => $news, 'finalNews' => $finalNews]);
```

How can I exclude the last news? I am using Laravel and MySQL.

Comment: Please don't rollback valid edits that improve the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use following code

```
$finalNews = News::find(DB::table('news')->max('id'));

$news = News::where('id','<>',$finalNews->id)->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Comment: that worked properly. I tried doing this before I asked but seems like I made sytax errors. now it is all as it's spossed to be. thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

Exclude the Id of latest news from the news list

```
$finalNews = News::find(DB::table('news')->max('id'));

$latestId = $finalNews->id;

$news = News::where('id','!=',$latestId)
        ->orderBy('id','desc')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

First, get all news

```
$news = News::orderBy('id','desc')->get();
```

Then, pop the last item (the lastest news) out of $news

```
$latest_news = $news->pop();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pop

There is no need to use 2 queries in this case